# Power cog is gone from the panel

Tags: 11.10, power-cog

I've tried the solution from here [The "power cog" has disappeared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61967/the-power-cog-has-disappeared) but that doesn't solve anything, I have indicator-session installed but the cog is gone still. Is this a know issue at this stage and will it be fixed come release day?

Comment: This is a bug: https://launchpad.net/bugs/854292

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/bugs/854292) and as such is now closed. For work-arounds, patches, and updates please subscribe to the bug on LaunchPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run `killall unity-panel-service` and the panel will restart (bringing the cog back).

Comment: very true - but it is still off-topic since it is a beta transient issue...

Comment: Perhaps we should have a tag for those issues so that they are answerable as long as the problems exist, but also easily removable when they become obsolete?

Comment: I would like to see something like that but I'm sure most people would disagree.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today actually.  You probably has just downloaded an update.  I did and after that the cog disappeared, then after a reboot, it came back.  You can follow what Roland Taylor said to kill the panel service which restarts it to fix it.

And most importantly...
Keep in mind...
It's a BETA release :)